# Cannot connect click eventhandler to button in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am creating a small webservice, which needs a button to recenter the map to a predefined point. Which seemed to be a one-minute requirement has kept me busy for the last 2 hours.

The script is using ArcGis Js api 3.9.

This is the code in question:

```
//ClickEvent To reCenter the map
var ReCenterButton = dom.byId('btnReCenter');
ReCenterButton.on('click', function (e) { 
     map.centerAndZoom(new Point(14, 51), 9);
});
```

Markup:

```
<button id="btnReCenter" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button">ReCenter</button>
```

The line `ReCenterButton = dom.byId(/* { ... } */);` throws the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are several errors here, first of all there is no Dojo 3.9, I suppose this is a typo and you mean Dojo 1.9.

The error you got means it cannot find a function, probably because you didn't import the `dojo/dom` module and thus it cannot find the `dojo/dom::byId()` function. Make sure the module is properly included in your `require()` and it is mapped upon a variable called `dom`, for example:

```js
require([ "dojo/dom" ], function(dom) {
    var ReCenterButton = dom.byId("btnReCenter");
});
```

However, a DOM node has **no** `on()` function, so this could be the reason of the error as well. When you're using `dojo/dom::byId()` it will return a plain DOM node. However, if you're working with widgets like `dijit/form/Button` you should rather use the `dijit/registry::byId()` function, for example:

```js
require([ "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/parser" ], function(registry, ready) {
    ready(function() { // Wait until the HTML markup is parsed and the widgets are instantiated
        var ReCenterButton = registry.byId('btnReCenter'); // Use dijit/registry
        ReCenterButton.on('click', function (e) {
            map.centerAndZoom(new Point(14, 51), 9);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Indeed a typo. I meant `http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/`. Will fix it. Using registry: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined `.

Comment: The ready function finally solved it, after I removed `dojo/domReady!` from the requirements and replaced it with `dojo/ready`. Thank you!